# Uploading a file for a new repository in GitHub

Tags: github

I'm having a problem of creating a new repository in GitHub so your help would be appreciated.
I've been using GitHub so I know how to upload the files etc. I've mainly uploaded only HTML and CSS files so far and it's been working fine. However, I've recently created files of HTML, CSS and JavaScript and I'm having a problem of uploading file...

For example, this is HTML and CSS based files that worked properly in GitHub.
https://totoblog.github.io/fm_fylo_landing_page_with_two_column_layout/
https://github.com/totoBlog/fm_fylo_landing_page_with_two_column_layout.git

And this is the file I am having a problem with. It doesn't show the page properly as I see on my desktop (see the below screenshot)

https://totoblog.github.io/janken/

https://github.com/totoBlog/janken.git

[image]

Thank you very much for your help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the page is not showing up on https://totoblog.github.io/janken/ is that you have placed the html, js and css files under https://github.com/totoBlog/janken/tree/master/janken instead of under https://github.com/totoBlog/janken, so there's an extra `janken` folder within which the required files are present.

So you need to either

- move the files within the `janken` folder to https://github.com/totoBlog/janken, to be able to use https://totoblog.github.io/janken/ for serving the page
- or you need to add the extra `janken` to the url as https://totoblog.github.io/janken/janken/, where you'll see the page being served

Comment: Hi Madhu. Thank  you very much for your comment and I have now solved the problem. Much appreciated. ‍♂️